# How does DES Encryption work in LM Hashing?

Tags: python, windows, hash, cryptography, lm

So, I'm trying to learn how older Windows systems hashes user passwords works. According to https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/lmhash, the plain-text password:

1) Is converted to uppercase and null-padded up to 14 bytes

2) The 14-byte password is split into two 7-byte hashes

3) The 7-byte values are used to create two 64-bit DES keys (with the addition of a parity bit for every seven bits)

4) Each key uses DES (using ECB) to encrypt the string "KGS!+#$%", which gives two 8-byte cipher values.

I'm trying to hash the password "PassWord123" (which is an example used on [this](http://techgenix.com/How-Cracked-Windows-Password-Part1/) techgenix article).

Applying the steps above, I got (please feel free to correct me if I'm doing anything wrong):

1) PASSWORD123000

2) PASSWOR and D123000

3) PASSWOR1 and D1230001

4) 9F85D1B92510E5B3 and C477143B02BC6ACF (used both [this](https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/) tool and a Python script to find these values)

Although, step 4 should give me E52CAC67419A9A22 and 664345140A852F61 (using the calculator from https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/lmhash and another Python script).

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: you must pad with zero bytes, not ASCII "0"s, and your parity calculation is simply wrong. reread those sections.

Comment: How is the parity calculation done?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but recently I was trying to do the same thing while learning about LM hashes.

As comments pointed out, the `0`'s as padding are NULL bytes, literal `\x00` characters.
Then a second possible issue is the fact that the site mistakingly says `"KGS!+#$%"` is the string that is encrypted, while it is actually the `"KGS!@#$%"` string instead (notice the `@` instead of `+`).

A key is split into chunks of 7 characters, but most DES functions require 8 bytes as a key. Therefore you require expanding the hash with parity bits which is a slightly complicated procedure, but has already been done in libraries like [passlib](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.crypto.des.html). Running their `des.expand_des_key` function on the 7-character chunk will give you the 8-byte key for DES encryption.

Putting this all together, we can do the calculation semi-manually like this in Python:

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import DES  # pycryptodome
from passlib.utils import des  # passlib


def lm(plaintext: bytes):
    plaintext = plaintext.upper()
    plaintext = plaintext.ljust(14, b"\x00")
    
    key1, key2 = des.expand_des_key(plaintext[:7]), des.expand_des_key(plaintext[7:])
    print(key1, key2)
    hash1 = DES.new(key1, DES.MODE_ECB).encrypt(b"KGS!@#$%")
    hash2 = DES.new(key2, DES.MODE_ECB).encrypt(b"KGS!@#$%")
    
    return hash1 + hash2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(lm(b"PassWord123").hex())
    # e52cac67419a9a22664345140a852f61
```

This correctly calculates the `E52CAC67419A9A22` and `664345140A852F61` sections and shows the intermediate 8-byte keys are almost unrecognizable (`b'P Tj4\xba<\xa4'` and `b'D\x18LF0\x00\x00\x00'`).

Comment: I know I am breaking a Stack Overflow rule by using a comment to express gratitude, but I will do it anyway. Thank you very much for your detailed answer :). It's never too late to learn something new. Unfortunately I need at least 15 reputation to upvote your answer.